# Unexpected '<' error for post while using Postman and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postman

My JSON response to be populated is as follows:

```
{
    "vendor":
    {
     "name": "Mozelle Luettgen MD",
     "email": "tyqmn@example.net",
     "phone_no": "9999997660",
     "addressline1": "Kulas Stravenue",
     "addressline2": "64636 Lynch Springs",
     "landmark": "Apt. 142",
     "city": "South Hannaview",
     "state": "North Dakota",
     "country": "Palau",
     "pincode": "53912-6122",
     "latitude": 50.8247548421224,
     "longitude": -81.8429583068792,
     "status": true
    } 
 }
```

My controller code for create vendor is

```
  def create 
    @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @vendor.save
      format.html { redirect_to @vendor, notice: 'Vendor was                         
      successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vendor, 
      :msg => { :status => "ok" , :result => @vendor.json, :message =>  
      "Succesfully Created" }
      }
    else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @vendor.errors, status: 
     :unprocessable_entity, 
     :msg =>
     { :status => "Error", :message =>  "Unprocessable Entity" }
     }
   end
  end
end


  def vendor_params
  params.require(:vendor).permit(:name, :email, :phone_no,
     :addressline1, :addressline2, :landmark, 
    :city, :state, :country, :pincode, :latitude, :longitude, :status, 
    {products_attributes: [:id, :product_name, :price]},
    {vendor_products_attributes: [:id, :vendor_product_id, :vendor_id,             
   :product_id, :copies, :_destroy]})
end
```

While running this link http://localhost:3000/vendors/create_vendor with post, the status shows 200 ok, but when I look for the JSON response,for the created vendor, it throws Unexpected '<' error.What am I doing wrong.Can someone please elaborate

[image]

Comment: did you check by using debugger, what params you are getting on controller?

Comment: I have updated the question displaying the params permitted.

Comment: I think @power is asking for a debugger view of what params are actually present in the controller when you run the transaction in Postman.

Comment: Oh right @Power ...well checking on params on binding.pry, I get the following params : {"vendor"=>
  {"name"=>"Mozelle Luettgen MD",
   "email"=>"ajczzz@example.net",
   "phone_no"=>"9999997660",
   "addressline1"=>"Kulas Stravenue",
   "addressline2"=>"64636 Lynch Springs",
   "landmark"=>"Apt. 142",
   "city"=>"South Hannaview",
   "state"=>"North Dakota",
   "country"=>"Palau",
   "pincode"=>"53912-6122",
   "latitude"=>50.8247548421224,
   "longitude"=>-81.8429583068792,
   "status"=>true},
 "controller"=>"vendors",
 "action"=>"create"}. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What happens if you edit your JSON return structure and change `location: @vendor` to `:location => @vendor.id`?

Comment: @JohnFeltz...it works same as when the value was location: vendor...So no changes occurring there

Comment: Well all I can suggest is that you start stripping things out of the JSON return until you find the thing that's breaking.  Are you sure that the `@vendor.json` method works?

Comment: Well the thing is , even if I room the message part of the code, the one with @vendor.json , it will still show the same error.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I've just encountered the same `Unexpected '<'` response. It turns out this is just a message from Postman's pretty-printing. Switch to the raw output to see the actual response.

Comment: This recently happened to me. For anyone seeing this now - make sure your URL is correct...forgot to add `/x` with a url scheme of `/x/y`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to get it sorted by changing the syncing link

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not  have declared twice this var `User=require('../Models/user');` object of model class both in `route/user.js` and main `server/app.js file`

You declared object two times of model class

Answer (score 0):

This Setting in postman application helped me to resolve this problem

Global Proxy Configuration:ON

Proxy Type: HTTPS

Proxy Server: abc.xyz.abc.com:8080

Use System Proxy: OFF

Answer (score -2):

The reason is that you might have opened the session by logging into another browser or some where else while trying to connect to postman. That is the reason you are getting "unexpected '>'".

To avoid that, login to postman with the login api and try to hit your service. It will work for sure.